# How to convert an array of integer into a single integer

Tags: algorithm

Using pseudo-code, if I have an array of integer, how can I make a single big integer that represents the same array in bits?

Example of input (using bits):

[10101, 10001, 00010, 01100]

The integer should be:
10101100010001001100
or
01100000101000110101

Comment: Are all inputs taken to be the same number of bits in length? (in your example, 5, with a desired integer of length 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number = 0
for each element e
   number *= 1 + maximumRepresentableNumber
   number += e
```

For your example, `maximumRepresentableNumber` will be `11111`, as that is the maximum number we can represent using the allowed number of bits (5). Adding 1 to that gives us `100000`, and, if we multiply by that, it will be equivalent to a bit-shift by 5 to the left.

This would work for decimal representation as well, i.e. `[123, 55, 29]` will return `123055029`. In this case `maximumRepresentableNumber` will be `999`, so we'd just be multiplying by `1000`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is well known in functional programming land as *fold* or *reduce*. The basic idea is, that in a list

```
a,b,c,d, ..., x
```

we replace the commas with an operation we want (the operation beig symbolaized by `$` here):

```
a $ (b $ (c $ (d $ ...(x $ Z)))        // right fold
```

and the empty list with some default value `Z`

A bit different is the left fold, where we start out with `Z`:

```
((((Z $ a) $ b) $ c ).... $ x)))
```

The genral imperative algorithm for left fold would be:

```
result = Z
for each e in list do result = result $ e
```

Now, the only problem left is to identify `$` and `Z`, that is the function we want to apply subsequently to all list elements to reach the goal and the starting value. In your case, what you want is either:

- append the stringified element to the result string. `Z` is the empty string.
- **or**: add the element to the result so far multiplied with 2^5. `Z` would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby:

```
answer = 0
[0b10101, 0b10001, 0b00010, 0b01100].each do |x|
  answer <<= 5
  answer |= x
end

puts answer.to_s(2) # 10101100010001001100
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python this would be:

```
a = [0b10101, 0b10001, 0b00010, 0b01100]
b = 0
for elem in a:
    b <<= elem.bit_length()
    b += elem
print(bin(b))
```